# starting app from the same status as user had quit it

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Suppose user is at any viewcontroller in app and  filling the form the (view controller can be any viewcontroller).
Now he quits the app also from background.

So when user again starts the app  i need to show the viewcontroller with same status he had quit it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to save those field values - and what view is being shown - to some persistent storage (write to a plist for example)...depending on the layout of your app, you could do that each time the `applicationWillEnterBackground`, or `applicationWillTerminate`, or maybe every time `textFieldDidEndEditing`...then you'll need to recall that data on re-launch

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/data-persistence-in-iphone/

Comment: hi thanks for reply , my app has been quited from background also so when app relaunches then it will start from the begining(rootviewcontroller) so here requirement is to start the app from the view controller at which it was closed that may be viewcontroller no 2,3,4 etc

Comment: right, so when the app enters background, save what viewcontroller is being shown, and then on relaunch, read that saved data, and push the correct view...then fill the fields with the other saved data

Comment: ok suppose i am at the viewcontroller 4 of tab 2 of my app and when app relaunches i push that view by automatically selecting tab 2. now if user taps on back button to go to viewcontroller 3 of tab 2 then will it crash please clear my doubt

Comment: You'll only have e few seconds to save the states while the app is entering the background.

Comment: Maybe you need to load the whole stack in order? I'm not sure since I don't know how your views relate to one another

Comment: hello everyone thanks for your reply i got a link to apple documentation where this scenario has been discussed i understood what they want to tell but i need some starting code help if any one of you can help me then it will be a great help for me. The link to the documentation is http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/iphoneappprogrammingguide.pdf   page no 92.